# gpg - how can I encrypt, sign, and decrypt without importing any keys

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I'm I have two public and private key pairs that I am experimenting with.  Let's call them:

```
private-recipient.asc
public-recipient.asc
private-sender.asc
public-sender.asc
```

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a message with gpg without "importing" any keys.  I seem to be able to encrypt it with the receiver's public key directly from a file, but can only sign it by importing the signers private key.

This works:

```
gpg --import private-recipient.asc
gpg --import private-sender.asc
# and then trust them maybe
echo HELLO STACK OVERFLOW | gpg --encrypt --recipient-file public-recipient.asc --armor --sign --local-user sender@example.com > encrypted-message.txt
cat encrypted-message | gpg --decrypt
```

which says `HELLO STACK OVERFLOW` and a bunch of info about the key

However, I would like to run several independent experiments in different directories... so I am hoping to do something more like this:

```
## CAUTION MOST PARAMS IN HERE ARE MADE UP
echo HELLO STACK OVERFLOW | gpg --encrypt --armor --recipient-file public-recipient.asc --sign-with-key private-sender.asc > encrypted-message.txt
cat encrypted-message.txt | gpg --descrypt --recipient-private-key private-recipient.asc --check-signature public-sender.asc
```

But as far as I can tell, most of those arguments don't exist.  Is there a way to do it without importing any keys?